# Why am i getting error whenever i tried to use, example: "with open('file.txt') as my_new_file.txt: " on Jupyter Notebook Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm a still trying to learn Python but i don't know why my Jupyter Notebook is showing SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing.

%%writefile my_file.txt
Can you imagine that i can be this successfull
nobody ever believes what i am today
they are all surprise to see me successful
well! it is all God's doing

my_content = open('my_file.txt')

with open('my_file.txt') as my_new_file.txt:

Comment: `my_new_file.txt` is not a valid Python name.

Comment: Are those plain ASCII single-quotes around the filename?  Or is one of them an "angled" quote?

Comment: @KlausD. That would be a NameError, not unexpected EOF.

Answer (score 0):

First, "my_new_file.txt" won't work for a python variable name as you're using it; remove ".txt". Second, for with... commands, you need to have an action associated with it. For example:

```py
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as my_new_file:
    contents = my_new_file.read()
for line in contents:
   ...
```